# Sharepoint Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am using hjavascript:void window.open('http://www.microsoft.com') to open the link in a new tab.

But I get the error following error message:

In Firefox:

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (hjavascript) isn't associated with any program.

IN IE: it displays the following error:

The webpage cannot be displayed

Most likely cause:
•Some content or files on this webpage require a program that you don't have installed.

What you can try: 
     Search online for a program you can use to view this web content.

```
 Retype the address.  

 Go back to the previous page.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already pointing out the error.

```
hjavascript:
```

should be

```
javascript:
```

Comment: @Hari Gillala If Pekka's answer solved your problem, you can click the big checkmark to accept his answer.